# Regarding .gvfs not letting delete a user's home directory

Tags: linux, fedora

I am using *Fedora 9*. I removed the user using `userdel -r` command. The user is removed, but the home directory still remains. When I tried to remove the home directory (*rm -rf /home/user/*), I get the following message:

`rm: cannot remove '/home/user/.gvfs': Permission denied`

This happens on random occasions. Which scenario does this occur? Why is this occurring?

Comment: By the way, this should only happen if the user is logged into a Gnome session.  You shouldn't be removing the home directories of people who are logged in.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for the reply. I did the delete user operation after logging out the user. Point to note is: userdel -r command has deleted the user. If the user was logged in, the userdel wont delete the user. Only the home directory remains and it is empty.

Comment: On an unrelated but important note: please upgrade from Fedora 9, which is three years past end of life.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you're getting that error instead of `Device or resource busy`. Nonetheless, I suspect the problem is that something is mounted there. The first step is to check for processes running as the deleted user and kill them all. (If you've removed the user account, you'll have to find them in the process table via the numeric uid.) There's *probably* something like `gvfs-fuse-daemon` running. Once that's gone, you should have no problem removing everything.

(It's reasonable to run `killall -u targetuser; sleep 5; killall -9 -u targetuser` before running `userdel -r targetuser`.)